# Java subtract months without Library

Tags: java, date, math, calendar

I want to subtract months from integer without any library.

The problem is that when I reduce 1 month from first month : 0 (January) it should be 12 (Dec) but it will be -1..

This is my code for adding

```
    int currentMonthInt = Integer.parseInt(currentMonth) - 1;
    int currentYearInt = Integer.parseInt(currentYear);

    // show today month
    if (dateposition == 0){
        showListView(currentMonth, currentYear, db);
    }

    // show next month
    for (int i = 1; i <=200; i++){
        if (dateposition == i){
            int month = currentMonthInt + i;
            int year = currentYearInt + (month / 12);
            month = (month % 12)+1;

            String monthString = String.format("%02d", month);
            String yearString = String.valueOf(year);
            showListView(monthString, yearString, db);
        }
    }
```

and this is my code for subtracting : (but it dosen't work)

```
    for (int i = -200; i < 0; i++){
            //This is not correct!
            //int month = currentMonthInt + i;
            //int year = currentYearInt + (month / 12);
            //month = (month % 12)+1;

            String monthString = String.format("%02d", month);
            String yearString = String.valueOf(year);
            showListView(monthString, yearString, db);
    }
```

P.S. **dateposition**  is for position of month if its 0 its today months and year and if its +1 its next month and so on and if its -1 its prev month

Comment: Try to use [Joda](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) library

Comment: code for subtracting `month = (month % 12)+1;`  are you sure its correct? , In case if you have month 0 even in this condition above formula will return you one only.

Comment: `a % b` may give a negative number when `a` is negative.

Comment: code for subtracting is not correct I am just asking for that...

Comment: As Chris said use joda time.

Comment: thanks but I want to do it without any library...

Comment: Please use a library. You will get it wrong otherwise. There are all sorts of non-trivial corner cases.

Comment: What is `dateposition` for?

Comment: dateposition  is for position of month if its 0 its today months and year and if its +1 its next month and so on and if its -1 its prev month

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I wrote it and I test it its worked!

```
    for (int i = -200; i < 0; i++){
        if (dateposition == i){
            int month = currentMonthInt + i;
            int year = currentYearInt + (month / 12);

            if (month >= 0){
                month = (month % 12)+1;
            } else {
                int c1 = Math.abs(month / 12) + 1;
                month += (12 * c1);
            }

            String monthString = String.format("%02d", month);
            String yearString = String.valueOf(year);
            showListView(monthString, yearString, db);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

Using [Joda library](http://www.joda.org/joda-time)

```
public void test() {
    LocalDate fromDate = LocalDate.now();
    System.out.println(fromDate);
    LocalDate newYear = fromDate;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        newYear = newYear.minusMonths(1);
        System.out.print(newYear + ", ");
    }
    System.out.println("\n-------");
    newYear = fromDate;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        newYear = newYear.plusMonths(1);
        System.out.print(newYear + ", ");
    }
}
```

Output:

```
2014-10-20
2014-09-20, 2014-08-20, 2014-07-20, 2014-06-20, 2014-05-20, 2014-04-20, 2014-03-20, 2014-02-20, 2014-01-20, 2013-12-20, 
-------
2014-11-20, 2014-12-20, 2015-01-20, 2015-02-20, 2015-03-20, 2015-04-20, 2015-05-20, 2015-06-20, 2015-07-20, 2015-08-20,
```